# Wineskin: where does it download and install wine-mono and gecko?

Tags: wine, sound-volume, windows

I've started using [Wineskin](http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com) and, when I created the first wrapper, it told me that it couldn't find mono and gecko and that it could download and install them for me. The prompts were X11 modals managed by Wine.

It downloaded and installed them, and I can find them in the created wrappers, but I don't know where the source files have been downloaded to. They're not in `~/Library/Application Support/Wineskin`.

I want to know where they are just because I don't want to leave behind useless large files when I'm done with Wineskin.

Comment: I can't create new tags, but I think that this question needs the `wineskin` tag. Can anyone create it for me please?

Comment: I'm pretty darn sure it's inside of the wrapper. If you transfer the wrapper to a new machine, the wrapper will work without redownloading anything (as is the purpose of Wineskin).

Comment: there you go `wineskin` tag

Comment: yes @Wowfunhappy, they're in the wrappers, but since it doesn't prompt me to download them every time, it must have stored them somewhere so that it can reuse them. I'm trying to find out where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've kept digging and I've located them in `~/.cache/wine/`, which contains `wine-mono-4.7.1.msi` and `wine_gecko-2.47-x86.msi`, both created when I created the first wrapper.

Comment: You can accept your own answer by the way ;)

Comment: I guess I will, since it might be useful to others too.

Comment: @Manchineel it's not possible to accept one's own answer until two days have passed since the question was posted.

Comment: oh I see sorry, I didn't know